# Magento 2 - All products page with layered navigation and pagination

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, filter, category-products, pagination

I want to create all product page with the `filters`, `toolbar`, `pagination`.

I can do it by creating a new category with the name `All Products` and assign all products in it. But I guess this is not a good approach, as if every time new products added to the website it should also be added to All Products category. There is a lot of chances of human error.

Is there a way of calling a category page with the root level category? like from `ID: 2`

It's okay if anyone doesn't want to write code for me, but if anyone can help me find an approach to do it that would be great.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I recently did the same sort of work. First you need to override Category block because you want the All products page just like category page. In order to, get more understanding check **getCurrentCategory()** function which set the current category to root category

Path: `app\code\Vendor\AllProducts\Block\Category\View.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\AllProducts\Block\Category;

/**
 * Class View
 * @api
 * @package Magento\Catalog\Block\Category
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * Catalog layer
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer
     */
    protected $_catalogLayer;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category
     */
    protected $_categoryHelper;

    protected $priceHelper;

    protected $_storeManager;

    protected $categoryRepository;

    protected $_request;

    protected $productFactory;

    protected $eavconfig;   
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $priceHelper,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavconfig,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
        $this->priceHelper = $priceHelper;
        $this->_catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->eavconfig = $eavconfig;

        parent::__construct($context, $layerResolver, $registry, $categoryHelper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();


        $this->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Breadcrumbs::class);

        $category = $this->getCurrentCategory();
        if ($category) {
            $title = $category->getMetaTitle();
            if ($title) {
                $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set($title);
            }
            $description = $category->getMetaDescription();
            if ($description) {
                $this->pageConfig->setDescription($description);
            }
            $keywords = $category->getMetaKeywords();
            if ($keywords) {
                $this->pageConfig->setKeywords($keywords);
            }
            if ($this->_categoryHelper->canUseCanonicalTag()) {
                $this->pageConfig->addRemotePageAsset(
                    $category->getUrl(),
                    'canonical',
                    ['attributes' => ['rel' => 'canonical']]
                );
            }

            $pageMainTitle = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('page.main.title');
            if ($pageMainTitle) {
                $pageMainTitle->setPageTitle($this->getCurrentCategory()->getName());
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getProductListHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('product_list');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve current category model object
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category
     */

    //**** This function set the current category to root level category which is 2 in my case ****//
    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {
        if (!$this->hasData('current_category')) {

            if ($this->_request->getModuleName() == "allproducts"){
            $category = $this->categoryRepository->get(2, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
            }
            else {
            $category = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_category');
            }
            $this->setData('current_category', $category);
        }

        return $this->getData('current_category');
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCmsBlockHtml()
    {
        if (!$this->getData('cms_block_html')) {
            $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                \Magento\Cms\Block\Block::class
            )->setBlockId(
                $this->getCurrentCategory()->getLandingPage()
            )->toHtml();
            $this->setData('cms_block_html', $html);
        }
        return $this->getData('cms_block_html');
    }

    /**
     * Check if category display mode is "Products Only"
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isProductMode()
    {
        return $this->getCurrentCategory()->getDisplayMode() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::DM_PRODUCT;
    }

    /**
     * Check if category display mode is "Static Block and Products"
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isMixedMode()
    {
        return $this->getCurrentCategory()->getDisplayMode() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::DM_MIXED;
    }

    /**
     * Check if category display mode is "Static Block Only"
     * For anchor category with applied filter Static Block Only mode not allowed
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isContentMode()
    {
        $category = $this->getCurrentCategory();
        $res = false;
        if ($category->getDisplayMode() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::DM_PAGE) {
            $res = true;
            if ($category->getIsAnchor()) {
                $state = $this->_catalogLayer->getState();
                if ($state && $state->getFilters()) {
                    $res = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return $res;
    }

    /**
     * Return identifiers for produced content
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getIdentities()
    {
        return $this->getCurrentCategory()->getIdentities();
    }
}
```

Add block Path: `app\code\Vendor\AllProducts\Block\Index\Index.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\AllProducts\Block\Index;


class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context, array $data = []) {

        parent::__construct($context, $data);

    }


    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

}
```

Add Front controller, path should be like: `app\code\Vendor\AllProducts\Controller\Index\Index.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\AllProducts\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    private $context;
    private  $response;
    private  $redirect;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    private $url;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->context = $context;
        $this->response = $context->getResponse();
        $this->redirect = $context->getRedirect();
        $this->url = $url;
        //return 
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }

    public function getResponse()
    {
        return $this->response;
    }
}
```

Add `di.xml` in your module for overriding guidance
Path: `app\code\Vendor\AllProducts\etc\di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" type="Vendor\AllProducts\Block\Category\View" />
</config>
```

Override `catalog_category_view.xml` in your module. Path should be like: `app\code\Vendor\AllProducts\view\frontend\layout\allproducts_index_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigationStaging\Block\Navigation\Category" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/view.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State" name="catalog.navigation.state" as="state" />
                <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" name="catalog.navigation.renderer" as="renderer" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/filter.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.products" template="Magento_Catalog::category/products.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
                    <container name="category.product.list.additional" as="additional" />
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
                        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="category.product.type.details.renderers.default" as="default"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="category.product.addto" as="addto">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                               name="category.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                               template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    </block>
                    <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
                    </action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Thanks Muhammad, Let me try this solution.

Comment: Thanks worked for me :)

Comment: @MuhammadHasham It's layout display wrong and swatches and layered navigation also not display. How to solve it?

Comment: Can you please help me here? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/292878/77631

Comment: @MuhammadHasham I want to display child category also in category list. Do you know how to display that? I display "Default category" in all product page.